# I need a substitute as coroutines and iterators cannot have out or ref parameters

Tags: unity-game-engine, iterator, coroutine

I am loading textures from URL by using www in c# unity. As there are multiples textures, I want to load them asynchronously and show them in the unity 4.6 Image by changing them into sprite so for that I want to pass the Image reference as out parameter to the coroutine that in turn will yield the texture.
I have tried callback/delegates but that doesn't serve my purpose. 
help me solve this issue.
i just want these images to be assigned to the UI element and don't want to store them manually and assigning them later. As that is not the best approach. although the approach i am using is also not what it should, so suggest me how can i make this happen effortlessly.

Comment: Why don't callbacks or delegates serve your purpose? What have you tried? Could you show us? Or at least clarify what it is you did and why that won't work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this coroutine with callbacks

```c#
StartCoroutine(Request(delegate(WWW www){
    print("Success");
    //do something with www.texture here
},delegate(WWW www){
    print("Failure");
}));


IEnumerator Request(System.Action<WWW> SuccessCallback, System.Action<WWW> FailureCallback) {
    WWW www = new WWW("http://my-page.com/");   
    yield return www;
    if(www.error == null){
        SuccessCallback(www);       
    } else {
        FailureCallback(www);
    }       
}
```

Comment: Great ! Worked Just fine